# How can i import custom table data into google analytics by api?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, dataset, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to import my user information table data to google analytics by api?
my project based on PHP, Laravel. I can't find any useful thing for my project to import my table data to google analytics by api.